# Simplify Logarithmic Equations

Tags: logarithms

How to I simplify these two equations for E

1) 8.6 = 2/3log(E/10^4.4)

2) 5.6 = 2/3log(E/10^4.4)

Comment: For one thing, the two equations are essentially identical, so if you know how to solve one you will know how to solve the other. Second, use LaTeX or mathjax to make your question a bit more legible. Third, let us know what work you have done so far, or what your thoughts are on how to complete this problem so we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constants are not well written so, I've solved it in terms of constants

$$a=b\log \left(\frac{x}{d}\right)$$

$$a\log e=\log \left(\frac{x}{d}\right)^{b}$$
($e$ is **not** any arbitrary constant here)
$$e^a=\left(\frac{x}{d}\right)^{b}$$

$$d^be^a=x^b$$

$$d^be^a=x^b$$
$$x=de^{a/b}$$
Now just plug in constants